# Change group in Django admin is very slow

Tags: django

Django 1.11

If I click Groups in Django admin site, I can see a list of groups. Namely, the address is http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/group/

I monitor the CPU usage in terminal. Python is consuming 4-5 % now.

I have organized 4 groups. So, if I click any group, the server just calculating something for several minutes. The address now is like http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/group/6/change/ 
Maybe about 5 minutes the server is calculating something. And Python is now consuming 100 % of CPU resources.

Well, Django admin is analyzing something.

I have about 23-25 models. Well, this is not a very big number of models.

Each model is 3 standard permissions (add, change, delete). And I created one permission myself in the Meta class of a model.

So, as soon as "Change group" page is in front of me with available permissions and chosen permissions, CPU consumption by Python is again 4-5 %.

Could you comment on this? Is it curable?

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer, since nobody knows exactly what your code is doing.  You need to narrow down the problem a bit more.  There is a lot that can go on based on your code.

Comment: I have no idea how to diagnose this problem. Could you recommend me something?

Comment: My best method of testing things is using pycharm's debug. Sometimes it can take hours to diagnose. It is rare that any problem is caused by django's code.

I would pout a stop point in your code that you know will be called when you go to groups, and just step through things until you find a very repetitive bit of code. Find out what the code is doing, and see how your code is interacting with it. If you then figure that out, update, or answer your question.

That's my only real suggestion, unfortunately. Wish I could be more help.

Comment: I don't seem to have touched permissions at all. Creating one permission may not cause this problem. I can switch it off easily. Can the reason be in abstract models? I used it a lot. I just don't know where to dig and where to put breakpoints.

Comment: If you have your users in AbstractBaseUser, that very well could be it.  Groups do rely on the User quite a bit.

I have had a hell of a time getting AbstractBaseUser to play nice in the past.

Comment: No. I didn't touch User. I just created 4 groups programmatically. And created some users for debug purposes. And append the users to groups. But my models do rely on other models inheriting from models.Model.

Answer (score 5):

Came across this issue when using django debug toolbar with the built in django admin app. The change/update page was incredibly slow locally (sometimes it would not load at all) but if I set `DEBUG=False` (thus turning the debug toolbar off) it worked as expected. In my particular case, I didn't need the debug toolbar for the admin app so I disabled it for only those admin URLS like so:

```
# settings.py

DEBUG = True

def show_toolbar(request):
    # disable debug toolbar for built in admin app urls only
    if request.path.startswith('/admin'):
        return False
    else:
        return True
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': show_toolbar,
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We're using the same setup as Max Malysh:

- Django 1.11
- A custom `User` model based on `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser`
- The custom user model set in the settings via `AUTH_USER_MODEL` variable

We've got the same issues and I think I found the issue, or at least the module which is causing the delays. It has nothing to do with Django and/or the `DEBUG` mode itself, because I think the issue is within the `debug_toolbar`.

If you deactivate the `debug_toolbar` application and `debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware` middleware, it works like a charm.

I didn't had the time to reverse-engineer it, but I'll have a look at it when I find the time. In the meantime and as a workaround, deactivate the debug toolbar if you don't need it.

Sorry, it's not a final solution yet, but I thought I'll share my findings in case they can help somebody.

Cheers
Domi

**EDIT/UPDATE:** It has something to do with the Template panel of the Debug Toolbar. If you deactivate it, you'll have a much faster response time!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem when adding a new group with `Debug=True` in `settings.py`.

The same code works fine with `Debug=False`.

Some background information:

- We use Django 1.11
- We use custom user model inheriting from `AbstractBaseUser`
- There are ~30 models registered on the admin site

Django debug toolbar output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same problem, but probably for a different reason than the OP was.

If you have a large number of Users, look at your `admin.py` and make sure that you are not displaying Users inline on the Group admin page. That can cause very slow loading of the Group admin page if the Group has a large number of users in it.